# Why does hxnormalize remove closing tags and quotes?

Tags: html, tags, standards, normalize

I'm trying to normalize HTML code using the command-line tool `hxnormalize`. For some reason the default behavior is that it removes the closing tags and quotes for tag attributes:

```
echo "<html lang=\"en\"><head></head></html>" | hxnormalize
```

Output:

```
<html lang=en>
  <head>
```

Why is that the default behavior of `hxnormalize`? Is this the preferred output by some HTML standard?

Comment: "Why is that the default behavior of hxnormalize?" — You're asking us to speculate on the author's intent here.

Comment: "Would this be preferred for HTML output?" — It's smaller and uses fewer bytes. Anything else I could say about it would be opinionated.

Comment: @Quentin I'm rather wondering whether there is a standard I'm not aware of which defines this as preferred output.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it more clear.